# Problems with Views and animations

Tags: android, animation, view, android-linearlayout

I have Linear Layouts that i want to replace each other on click.
At start: Linear Layout A is visible, Linear Layout B is gone
I want when A is clicked to be gone and B to be visible and vice versa.
without the animation it all worked just fine, but when i set animation after clicking B B is gone, but A is not visible although if i click in its place the Log gives me that it's visible
here's the code, any help would be appreciated

```
private void switchRowItems(final LinearLayout toBeHiddenRow,final LinearLayout toBeShownRow){
    toBeHiddenRow.animate()
            .rotation(toBeHiddenRow.getHeight()/2)
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    toBeHiddenRow.clearAnimation();
                    toBeHiddenRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    toBeShownRow.clearAnimation();
                    toBeShownRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
    //toBeShownRow.clearAnimation();
   // toBeShownRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

and the on click checker is as simple as:

```
 if (llRowTwoItemOne.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        Log.d("llRowTwoItemOne","visible");
    } else {
        Log.d("llRowTwoItemOne","not visible");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in this way:

1. Create xml file in res/anim resource directory. Let's call it myanimation.xml and write there:

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:duration="300">
    </rotate>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="200">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

You can see that it is a set of animations you need: rotation and alpha.

2. Then I write in the switchRowItem function this:

   ```
   private void switchRowItems(final LinearLayout toBeHiddenRow, final LinearLayout toBeShownRow){

   Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
   anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

           toBeHiddenRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           toBeShownRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
       }
   });
   toBeHiddenRow.startAnimation(anim);

   }
   ```

That's all. It works pretty well. Hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: THANKS ALOT IT WORKED but how do i set the rotation llRow.getHeight()/2 ??

Comment: @eshteghelcompany, you are welcome. I don't know this exactly. If there would only rotate animation then you could just use RotateAnimation class for this purpose. But you have a set of animations. So it makes things complicated. Maybe it is a question for another post? =)

Comment: Great! Just didn't understand what rotation method exactly does. Good luck!